# Update Sql if threshold is met

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

I am making a ranking system which checks if the user's XP meets a certain level then updates the database with their new rank. Here is my code currently.

```
 <?php
 session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$id=$_SESSION['user']['id'];
$sl = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
$reult = $conn->query($sl);

    while($ro = $reult->fetch_assoc()) {
if($ro['xp']>2000){
$sql = "UPDATE users SET rank='2' WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo"Success";
} 
} //ENDS THE IF
elseif($ro['xp']>"5000"){
$sel = "UPDATE users SET rank='3' WHERE id='$id'";

if ($conn->query($sel) === TRUE) {
    echo"Success";
}

}//ENDS ELSEIF


    }//WHILE LOOP ENDS
$conn->close();
    ?>
```

But PHP wont allow the `elseif's` to keep running if the first `if` is met. Is ther a better way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order you use.  1st check if the XP is > 5000, then 2000.

Comment: Select answer that is best/you use so question would be ,,answered''

Answer (score 1):

Just add another condition in the `if` :

```
if ($ro['xp'] > 2000 && $ro['xp'] <= "5000")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're actually bringing back more data than you actually need (you're only using the `xp` column that you select). So your statement:

```
$sl = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'";
```

can actually be reduced to the following:

```
$sl = "SELECT xp, rank FROM users WHERE id = '$id' AND xp > 2000";
```

(In general, using `SELECT *` is not a best practice.)

The `AND` clause is there because you don't need to update users with `xp` of 2000 or less -- so no need to retrieve them!

Why am I getting `rank`? Well, I'm also going to suggest you restructure your `if`:

```
while ($ro = $reult->fetch_assoc()) {
    $newrank = 2; // This is the default since any user retrieved will have xp > 2000
    if ($ro['xp'] > 5000) { // N.B. you have "5000" in quotes here - remove them!
        $newrank = 3;
    }
    if ($newrank != $ro['rank']) {
        // Update the user - no need to update if existing rank same as new!
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET rank='$newrank' WHERE id='$id'";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo"Success";
        } 
    }
} // end while
```

P.S. There is also the option of updating the users all at once rather than doing it user-by-user:

```
UPDATE users
   SET rank = CASE WHEN xp > 5000 THEN '3' ELSE '2' END
 WHERE xp > 2000;
```

It might be a good idea, in this vein, if you had a separate table of ranks and XP values:

```
RANKS
--------------------
rank  min_xp  max_xp
1     0       2000
2     2001    5000
3     5001    etc.
```

Then you can do the following:

```
UPDATE users u JOIN ranks r
    ON u.xp >= r.min_xp
   AND u.xp <= r.max_xp
   SET u.rank = r.rank;
```